# A Spiral of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to produce a spiral of numbers from 1 through 101 with the following properties:

-- multiples of 5 are in a node shaped like pentagon

-- there is a special starburst node at numbers 3, 6, 11, 13, 17, 23, 29, 37, 43, 52, 56, 61, 63, 68, 69, 71, 72, 80, 91, 99.

(I think one could use the `shapes.geometric` library to achieve both of these if only I could figure out how to switch styles at specific values of `\x` in the loop below.)

Here is where I am (with help from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/rooty-helix/)):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\hspace{0pt} \vfill
\begin{center}
  \newcounter{cntRoot}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (0:1);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
            \coordinate (c) at ($(b)!0.9cm!270:(a)$);
            \setcounter{cntRoot}{\x}
            \addtocounter{cntRoot}{1}
            \node[fill=white,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c)
                {$\thecntRoot$};
            \coordinate (b) at (c);
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{center}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

I tried to implement ideas from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157188/tikz-nodes-positions-and-shapes-with-a-general-number-of-nodes) answer without much success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am sure that there is a more efficient way of dealing with your starbursts (for example, using [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3)),  but the code below deals with them by first defining a comma separated list of special numbers and them looping through all of them to see if there is a match.  The numbers mod `5` are easy to deal with using `\pgfmathparseresult`.

The end result is then:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newif\ifnotfound% to mark the stars as we print them
\newcommand\starbursts{3,6,11,13,17,23,29,37,43,52,56,61,63,68,69,71,72,80,91,99}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (0:1);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
        \coordinate (c) at ($(b)!0.9cm!270:(a)$);
        \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,5))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
        \node[fill=white,draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,inner sep=1pt] at (c) {$\x$};
        \else
          \notfoundtrue% this will mark any starbursts
          \foreach \y in \starbursts {% check for stars
            \ifnum\x=\y% a star is born!
                \node[fill=white,draw,starburst,inner sep=1pt] at (c) {$\x$};
                \global\notfoundfalse% need \global as inside a loop
            \fi
          }
          \ifnotfound% we have not printed a node yet
        \node[fill=white,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (c) {$\x$};
          \fi
        \fi
        \coordinate (b) at (c);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Here's a [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) version. The code is much neater *but* it is also slower in the sense that my laptop returns the following timings:

> tikz: real 2.436  user 2.136  sys 0.281   pcpu 99.18
>
> tikz: real 2.479  user 2.169  sys 0.294   pcpu 99.34
>
> expl: real 2.557  user 2.250  sys 0.293   pcpu 99.45
>
> expl: real 2.552  user 2.238  sys 0.301   pcpu 99.49

The output is the same as above. Here's the revised code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.style = {fill=white,draw,inner sep=1pt}
}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_starbursts
\clist_set:Nn \l_starbursts {3,6,11,13,17,23,29,37,43,52,56,61,63,68,69,71,72,80,91,99}
\newcommand\SetNode[1]{
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 5 } = 0 }
    {\tikzset{mynode/.append~style={regular~polygon, regular~polygon~sides=5}}}
    {
      \clist_if_in:NoTF \l_starbursts {#1}
        {\tikzset{mynode/.append~style={starburst}}}
        {\tikzset{mynode/.append~style={circle}}}
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_if_in:NnTF {noTF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifnotfound% to mark the stars as we print them
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (0:1);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
        \coordinate (c) at ($(b)!0.9cm!270:(a)$);
        \SetNode{\x}
        \node[mynode] at (c) {$\x$};
        \coordinate (b) at (c);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT II**

Here is a third "plain TeX" approach following jfbu's suggestion and where the stars take precedence over the hexagons (unlike above, as pointed out by sgmoye in the comments). I switched to plain TeX because, surprisingly, using LaTeX3 sequences in a similar fashion led to slower code. Perhaps clists would be better? It could also be that the first solution draws the nodes directly whereas solutions II and III use some `\tikzset{...}` trickery. Anyway, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{
  mynode/.style = {fill=white,draw,inner sep=1pt}
}
\newcommand\starbursts{3,6,11,13,17,23,29,37,43,52,56,61,63,68,69,71,72,80,91,99}
\def\setnextstar#1,#2!{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\gdef\nextstar{200}\else\gdef\nextstar{#1}\gdef\starbursts{#2}\fi%
}
\expandafter\setnextstar\starbursts,,!

\newcommand\SetNode[1]{
  \ifnum#1=\nextstar
      \tikzset{mynode/.append style={starburst}}
      \expandafter\setnextstar\starbursts!
  \else
      \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,5))}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
         \tikzset{mynode/.append style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5}}
      \else
         \tikzset{mynode/.append style={circle}}
      \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (0:1);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
        \coordinate (c) at ($(b)!0.9cm!270:(a)$);
        \SetNode{\x}
        \node[mynode] at (c) {$\x$};
        \coordinate (b) at (c);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is slightly different in that `80` now has a star.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated!

Comment: (Also, the comment "a star is born" had me giggling! We stan the talent!)

Comment: @kan Glad to be helpful and to amuse:)

Comment: you could have an evolving list (comma separated or whatever) of starbursts: compare `\x` with the first: if `<` do nothing, if equal do the "star is born" and suppress that (leading) entry from list, if `>` you made a coding error somewhere. There should also be a flag to signal the starburst list is now empty.

Comment: I wondered what would happen if a number divisible by 5 were in the starburst list. Sure enough, `80` is just such a one: it is in the starburst list but is enclosed in a pentagon. Is this intended?

Comment: @sgmoye You're right I was assuming that the lists did not overlap/ As the code tests for divisibility by 5 first, the hexagons win. Perhaps the stars should win instead. It's easy enough to switch the loops

Comment: @Andrew I've tried some simple variations, but the pentagons seem to win.

Comment: @sgmoye Yes,  agreed: the hexagons will always win. I'll add a third variant following jfbu's suggestion that switches the loops so that the stars win.

Comment: Hey, for my purposes, this does not matter! I just wanted something to play around with!