# Foreach loop inside the Tikz picture - Creation of memory cards using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

This question regards creating a memory game using `Tikz`.I would like to ask for help with creating a loop that will place memory cards on the page.

There are many standards, I believe, but let us pick one:

1. memory game is printed on three pages, consisting of 32x2 square cards
2. two pages contain 4x6 cards, the third page contains 16 cards (the image bellow shows the layout)

The question is: How to place the cards in `foreach` loop, passing several arguments in array(s) of values? The array(s) of arguments will be: the name of the image file, the text, the colour value.

Pseudo `foreach` loop will look like this:
Place first image in array, place first title in array and use first colour in array; shift position by `xshift=71pt`, place second ...
After fourth image shift by `yshift`...

*Minor update*: Using this loop way it will be easy to create back of the cards passing the same value of image file. On the other hand all needs to be centred.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% ############################## geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 headsep = 0pt,
 headheight= 0pt, 
  hmarginratio =  1:1,
  vmarginratio = 1:1,
  bindingoffset = 0cm,
  onecolumn,
  a3paper,
  layoutwidth = 220 mm,
  layoutheight = 320 mm,
  layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
  layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax,
  showcrop
}
\usepackage[icelandic, latin, czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{16, 13, 32}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{XCharter}

% ############################### Document

\newcommand{\czHyphen}{\rule[.45ex]{.2em}{.11ex}}
\newcommand*{\addthinS}{\hskip0.06667em\relax}
\newcommand*{\addthinSS}{\hskip0.00007em\relax}
\def\cropmarkgap{1}% mm

\makeatletter
\def\Gm@cropmark(#1,#2,#3,#4){% #1 = x direction, #2 = y direction, #3 & #4 no longet used
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \setlength\unitlength{1truemm}%
    \linethickness{0.25pt}%
    \put(\the\numexpr #1*\cropmarkgap\relax,0){\line(#1,0){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
    \put(0,\the\numexpr #2*\cropmarkgap\relax){\line(0,#2){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
  \end{picture}}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{\drawbackground}
\newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-0.55\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}
\newcommand{\shiftup}{\vspace*{-0.13\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\tikzset{p_title/.style={text centered, minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=5cm, font=\bfseries}}
\tikzset{p_title_line/.style={ultra thin, color=violet}}

 \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(A.north west)$)  rectangle ($(A.south east)$);
 \node [p_title] (AA) at ($(A.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{title text}};
 \draw [p_title_line](AA.south west) -- (AA.south east);

 \node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at ([xshift=71pt]A.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$)  rectangle ($(B.south east)$);
\node [p_title] (BB) at ($(B.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{amma}};
 \draw [p_title_line](BB.south west) -- (BB.south east);

\node[inner sep=0pt] (C) at ([xshift=71pt]B.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(C.north west)$)  rectangle ($(C.south east)$);
 \node [p_title] (CC) at ($(C.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{banka}};
 \draw [p_title_line](CC.south west) -- (CC.south east);

 \node[inner sep=0pt] (D) at ([xshift=71pt]C.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(D.north west)$)  rectangle ($(D.south east)$);
  \node [p_title] (DD) at ($(D.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{strætó}};
 \draw [p_title_line](DD.south west) -- (DD.south east);

% second line 
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (E) at  ([yshift=-71pt]A.south)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(E.north west)$)  rectangle ($(E.south east)$);
 \node [p_title] (EE) at ($(E.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{bíll}};
 \draw [p_title_line](EE.south west) -- (EE.south east);

 \node[inner sep=0pt] (F) at ([xshift=71pt]E.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(F.north west)$)  rectangle ($(F.south east)$);
 \node [p_title] (FF) at ($(F.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{strætó}};
\draw [p_title_line](FF.south west) -- (FF.south east);

\node[inner sep=0pt] (G) at ([xshift=71pt]F.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(G.north west)$)  rectangle ($(G.south east)$);
  \node [p_title] (GG) at ($(G.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{banka}};
 \draw [p_title_line](GG.south west) -- (GG.south east);

 \node[inner sep=0pt] (H) at ([xshift=71pt]G.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
 \draw[black, ultra thick] ($(H.north west)$)  rectangle ($(H.south east)$);
  \node [p_title] (HH) at ($(H.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {{autobus}};
 \draw [p_title_line](HH.south west) -- (HH.south east);

%third line
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: pexeso]

Comment: I'd suggest using `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox`. It easily  produces  distribution of boxes like yours and it's possible to use a `foreach` loop inside it. Some examples  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251710/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214787/1952.

Comment: I will definitely have a look at it. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Using `tcbraster` can I position and align text over the image? I seems to me that I need image (with text and line) already ready as a whole. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using the standard TeX "array" approach ([an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37429/89497)): use `\csname` - `\endcsname` (or in this case the LaTeX wrappers `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse`) to define control sequences with numbers (i.e., the array index).

For your project, this requires three "arrays" one for the image name, the card title, and the card color. Here is the set up for the interface:

```
%%% Define "Array" interface
\makeatletter
    \newcounter{imgs}
    \setcounter{imgs}{0}
    %#1 is the image
    %#2 is the title
    %#3 is the color
    \newcommand{\addimg}[3]{%
        \stepcounter{imgs}%
        \@namedef{imgimage\theimgs}{#1}%
        \@namedef{imgtitle\theimgs}{#2}%
        \@namedef{imgcolor\theimgs}{#3}}
    \newcommand{\getimage}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgimage#1}}%
    \newcommand{\gettitle}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgtitle#1}}%
    \newcommand{\getcolor}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgcolor#1}}%
\makeatother
```

"Elements" are added to the "arrays" through the `\addimg` command. For the 32 unique cards, this would look like:

```
%%% Define Cards
\addimg{example-image-A}{one}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{two}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{three}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{four}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{five}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{six}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{seven}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{eight}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{nine}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{ten}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{eleven}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twelve}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{thirteen}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{fourteen}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{fifteen}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{sixteen}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{seventeen}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{eighteen}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{nineteen}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty one}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty two}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty three}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty four}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty five}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty six}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty seven}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty eight}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty nine}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{thirty}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{thirty one}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{thirty two}{orange}%
```

"Elements" are accessed from their respective "arrays" through the appropriate "get" commands. This allows the for a single for loop to be used. Parameterizing the lengths and number of images per row:

```
%%% Global Setup
\newcommand\xspacing{71pt}%<== space between the images
\newcommand\yspacing{71pt}%<== vertical space between rows
\newcommand\imgperrow{4}%<== number of images per row
\tikzset{p_title/.style={text centered, minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=5cm, font=\bfseries}}
\tikzset{p_title_line/.style={ultra thin, color=violet}}

%%% Define primary for loop
\newcommand{\forloop}[2]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1,...,#2}%<==loop for each image in the array
    {
        \edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\getimage{\x}}};}%<==Edit to expand the file name
         \gonode%\node [inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\getimage{\x}}};%
        \draw [black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$) rectangle ($(B.south east)$);%
        \node [p_title] (AA) at ($(B.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {\gettitle{\x}};%
        \draw [p_title_line, color=\getcolor{\x}](AA.south west) -- (AA.south east);%
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(\x,\imgperrow)==0?1:0};%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
            \coordinate (left) at ([yshift=-\yspacing]left);
            \path let \p1=(left),\p2=(B.south) in coordinate (A) at (\x1,\y2-\yspacing);
        \else   
            \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\xspacing]B.east);%
        \fi
    }}
%%% Define the for loop for 2 images per row on third page
\newcommand{\forlooptwo}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\imgperrow{2}
    \let\originalxspacing\xspacing
    \def\xspacing{5*\originalxspacing}
    \forloop{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
```

The `\xshift` and `\yshift` are determined by computing [the modulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60817/89497) of the `count` and `\imgperrow`. `\forlooptwo` is used for the four rows on the third page where two spaces are skipped. This is achieved by redefining `\imgperrow` and `\xspacing`.

The three pages are then created with:

```
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %first page
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{1}{24}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %second page
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{25}{32}
        \forloop{1}{16}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %third page
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{17}{20}
        \forlooptwo{21}{28}
        \forloop{29}{32}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To yield:

[image: resulting pages]

The total MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% ############################## geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 headsep = 0pt,
 headheight= 0pt, 
  hmarginratio =  1:1,
  vmarginratio = 1:1,
  bindingoffset = 0cm,
  onecolumn,
  a3paper,
  layoutwidth = 220 mm,
  layoutheight = 320 mm,
  layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
  layoutvoffset=\dimexpr(\paperheight-\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname)/2\relax,
  showcrop
}
\usepackage[icelandic, latin, czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{title}{RGB}{16, 13, 32}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{XCharter}

% ############################### Document

\newcommand{\czHyphen}{\rule[.45ex]{.2em}{.11ex}}
\newcommand*{\addthinS}{\hskip0.06667em\relax}
\newcommand*{\addthinSS}{\hskip0.00007em\relax}
\def\cropmarkgap{1}% mm

\makeatletter
\def\Gm@cropmark(#1,#2,#3,#4){% #1 = x direction, #2 = y direction, #3 & #4 no longet used
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \setlength\unitlength{1truemm}%
    \linethickness{0.25pt}%
    \put(\the\numexpr #1*\cropmarkgap\relax,0){\line(#1,0){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
    \put(0,\the\numexpr #2*\cropmarkgap\relax){\line(0,#2){\the\numexpr 20-\cropmarkgap}}%
  \end{picture}}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\AddToShipoutPicture{\drawbackground}
\newcommand{\shiftleft}{\hspace*{-0.55\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}
\newcommand{\shiftup}{\vspace*{-0.13\dimexpr\csname Gm@layoutheight\endcsname-\textwidth\relax}}


%%% Define "Array" interface
\makeatletter
    \newcounter{imgs}
    \setcounter{imgs}{0}
    %#1 is the image
    %#2 is the title
    %#3 is the color
    \newcommand{\addimg}[3]{%
        \stepcounter{imgs}%
        \@namedef{imgimage\theimgs}{#1}%
        \@namedef{imgtitle\theimgs}{#2}%
        \@namedef{imgcolor\theimgs}{#3}}
    \newcommand{\getimage}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgimage#1}}%
    \newcommand{\gettitle}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgtitle#1}}%
    \newcommand{\getcolor}[1]{\expandafter\@nameuse\expandafter{imgcolor#1}}%
\makeatother

%%% Define Cards
\addimg{example-image-A}{one}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{two}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{three}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{four}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{five}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{six}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{seven}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{eight}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{nine}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{ten}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{eleven}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twelve}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{thirteen}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{fourteen}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{fifteen}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{sixteen}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{seventeen}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{eighteen}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{nineteen}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty one}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty two}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty three}{orange}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty four}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty five}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty six}{brown}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{twenty seven}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{twenty eight}{blue}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{twenty nine}{green}%
\addimg{example-image-C}{thirty}{red}%
\addimg{example-image-A}{thirty one}{yellow}%
\addimg{example-image-B}{thirty two}{orange}%


%%% Global Setup
\newcommand\xspacing{71pt}%<== space between the images
\newcommand\yspacing{71pt}%<== vertical space between rows
\newcommand\imgperrow{4}%<== number of images per row
\tikzset{p_title/.style={text centered, minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=5cm, font=\bfseries}}
\tikzset{p_title_line/.style={ultra thin, color=violet}}

%%% Define primary for loop
\newcommand{\forloop}[2]{%
    \foreach [count=\i] \x in {#1,...,#2}%<==loop for each image in the array
    {
        \edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\getimage{\x}}};}%<==Edit to expand the file name
         \gonode%\node [inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\getimage{\x}}};%
        \draw [black, ultra thick] ($(B.north west)$) rectangle ($(B.south east)$);%
        \node [p_title] (AA) at ($(B.north west)+(2.5,-0.30)$) {\gettitle{\x}};%
        \draw [p_title_line, color=\getcolor{\x}](AA.south west) -- (AA.south east);%
        \pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,\imgperrow)==0?1:0};%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
            \coordinate (left) at ([yshift=-\yspacing]left);
            \path let \p1=(left),\p2=(B.south) in coordinate (A) at (\x1,\y2-\yspacing);
        \else   
            \coordinate (A) at ([xshift=\xspacing]B.east);%
        \fi
    }}
%%% Define the for loop for 2 images per row on third page
\newcommand{\forlooptwo}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\imgperrow{2}
    \let\originalxspacing\xspacing
    \def\xspacing{5*\originalxspacing}
    \forloop{#1}{#2}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %first page
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{1}{24}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %second page
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{25}{32}
        \forloop{1}{16}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %third page
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \coordinate (A) at (page cs:-0.5045,0.595);
        \coordinate (left) at (A);
        \forloop{17}{20}
        \forlooptwo{21}{28}
        \forloop{29}{32}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all - this is exactly what I needed. Thank you also for explaining the code itself! I have already implied the code to my recent version, though I have trouble now with loading the image. It says `LaTeX Error: File `auto.jpg' not found.` It works well with `mwe` image and also when I directly write `auto.jpg` inside the `\forloop` command. I set `\graphicspath` usual way (`\graphicspath{{/path/}{/path2/}}`)

Comment: I have found out that I have to write down the name of the image file without the extension. F.e. `\addimg{auto}{one}{blue}%` without `.jpg`. Everything works :)

Comment: @chejnik: You can expand the file name prior to declaring the node by using `\edef\gonode{\noexpand\node[inner sep=0pt] (B) at (A) {\noexpand\includegraphics[width=5cm]{\getimage{\x}}};}\gonode`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I left the previous code, loading images without file extension. I have added similar code for the back of the cards. I will post here a link to github complete code for creation of memory game cards, if you agree.

Comment: @chejnik: Happy to hear that this worked for you. Please, post a link. I'd be interested to see the result.

Comment: Ok. I have added the complete code to [github](https://github.com/chejnik/memory-cards-latex). Some option to use mwe images instead of real images (that users dont have) would be certainly useful. Best regards and many thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

This is just a simple example with `tcbraster`. You can fix columns number and distance between rows and columns, color of background boxes, titles, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, raster equal height=rows, size=fbox, colframe=red!50!black, center title]
\tcbincludegraphics[title=first]{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=second]{example-image-A}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=third]{example-image-B}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=fourth, colback=green]{example-image-C}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=first]{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=first, colframe=blue]{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=third]{example-image-B}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=second]{example-image-A}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=fourth]{example-image-C}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=second]{example-image-A}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=third]{example-image-B}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=first]{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=second]{example-image-A}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=fourth]{example-image-C}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=third]{example-image-B}
\tcbincludegraphics[title=fourth]{example-image-C}

\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've set `[raster columns=4, raster rows=6, raster width = 220mm, raster left skip=10mm, 
raster right skip = 10mm, raster height=300mm, raster before skip=10mm, raster after skip = 10mm, raster column skip = 0mm, 
raster row skip = 0mm, colframe=red!50!black, center title, arc=0mm, sharp corners]` with the geometry settings from my MWE. It seems there is no space to display all 6 rows.

Comment: When I use word 'hjól' with -j- letter, title area is bigger than areas of other titles. Using `adjusted title` option seems not to help. Is there no `height` of title area?

Comment: @chejnik For the problem with `j` you must use `adjusted title=...` in all boxes even those without `j`, this way all boxes in same row will adjust their title's height. Another solution could be keep using `title=...` in all boxes but including `before title=\strut` in `tcbraster` options.

Comment: @chejnik I didn't look at your `geometry` settings, but if you look where page number is shown, you'll see how it's impossible to fit 6 rows. I think there's something wrong in your page definition.

Comment: I see, the geometry settings was originally for `extbook` class, but nevertheless both classes sets it incorrectly. We will definitely find the solution:)